# MPLAB IDE Packs & XC8 Toolchains compatibility

Tags: compiler-errors, toolchain, mplab-5.45

An "old" project compiled fine on an "old" computer (OS Windows 8) using MPLAB IDE with Pack 1.0.9 and toolchain v1.42.

The identical project does not on my newer PC (OS Win 10) with (newer) Pack 1.2.26 and tool chain v2.31.

I installed the tool chain v1.42 on my PC. However, MPLAB ver 5.45 does not allow me to change the toolchain, options are greyed (see pls enclosed figure below)

NOTE: in both older and newer PCs the delopment SW is MPLAB IDE ver 5.45.

**Question 1:** can anybody tell me how to change the toolchain in the project?

**Question 2:** is it possible that the project does not compile on my newer PC because I am using a newer pack? Do packs should have back compatibility with older versions?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the older pack version 1.0.9 and it worked:
-the selection of toolchain version get enabled
-then  I chose the older toolchain and it simply complied!!
Hope it's useful to someone...